# Reading cread object twice causes 'IndexError: list index out of range'

Tags: python

When reading a csv reader object twice, getting the error 'IndexError: list index out of range'. Right now I'm creating a dictionary from iterating over the object, but fail when trying to create a similar list. Other code blocks are omitted for brevity, here is the pertinent code:

```
# Parse csv files for samples, creating a dictionary of key, value pairs and multiple lists.
with open('genes.csv') as f:
    cread = csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t')
    sample_1_dict = {i: float(j) for i, j in cread}
    sample_1_list = [x for x in sample_1_dict.items()]
    sample_1_genes_sorted = sorted(sample_1_list, key=lambda expvalues: expvalues[0])
    sample_1_values_sorted = sorted(sample_1_list, key=lambda expvalues: expvalues[1])
    sample_1_genes = [i for i, j in sample_1_values_sorted]
    sample_1_values = [j for i, j in sample_1_values_sorted]
    sample_1_graph_un = [float(j) for i, j in cread]

...

sample_values_list = [i for i in sample_1_graph_un, sample_2_graph_un, sample_3_graph_un, sample_4_graph_un, sample_5_graph_un, sample_6_graph_un]

sample_graph_list_un = [[i for i in sample_value] for sample_value in sample_values_list]

colors = 'bgrcmy'
alphas = ['0.5', '0.5', '0.5', '0.5', '0.5', '0.5']
labels = ['278', '470', '543', '5934', '6102', '17163']

for graph, color, alpha, label in zip(sample_graph_list_un, colors, alphas, labels):
    plt.hist(graph, bins = 21, histtype = 'stepfilled', normed = True, color = color, alpha = float(alpha), label=label)
```

I'm resorting to reopening the csv file, and the following code does work:

```
# Parse csv files for samples, creating a dictionary of key, value pairs and multiple lists.
with open('genes.csv') as f:
    cread = csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t')
    sample_1_dict = {i: float(j) for i, j in cread}
    sample_1_list = [x for x in sample_1_dict.items()]
    sample_1_genes_sorted = sorted(sample_1_list, key=lambda expvalues: expvalues[0])
    sample_1_values_sorted = sorted(sample_1_list, key=lambda expvalues: expvalues[1])
    sample_1_genes = [i for i, j in sample_1_values_sorted]
    sample_1_values = [j for i, j in sample_1_values_sorted]

...

with open('genes.csv') as f:
    cread = csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t')
    sample_1_graph_un = [float(j) for i, j in cread]

sample_values_list = [i for i in sample_1_graph_un, sample_2_graph_un, sample_3_graph_un, sample_4_graph_un, sample_5_graph_un, sample_6_graph_un]

sample_graph_list_un = [[i for i in sample_value] for sample_value in sample_values_list]
colors = 'bgrcmy'
alphas = ['0.5', '0.5', '0.5', '0.5', '0.5', '0.5']
labels = ['278', '470', '543', '5934', '6102', '17163']

for graph, color, alpha, label in zip(sample_graph_list_un, colors, alphas, labels):
    plt.hist(graph, bins = 21, histtype = 'stepfilled', normed = True, color = color, alpha = float(alpha), label=label)
```

The difference in each code example is the location of the below statement in either one of the two 'with' blocks:

```
sample_1_graph_un = [float(j) for i, j in cread]
```

Comment: Are you creating multiple variables with a number here? `sample_1_graph_un`, `sample_2_graph_un`, etc.? If so, don't. Use a list or dictionary instead. `sample_graph_un = []`, then `sample_graph_un.append([...])`. That saves you a lot of duplicated code as you can then use loops.

Comment: You talk about iterating over the iterator a few times, so presumably you know the basic concept, but I'm guessing you're confused by something that isn't spelled out too well in the docs. Iterators can only be iterated over once. If you try again, there are no values left to iterate. Files and csv readers are iterators. Meanwhile, some _iterables_ (such as lists) let you iterate over them as many times as you want (creating a new iterator each time). Other iterables (including iterators, which are themselves iterables) do not, giving you the same used-up iterator every time.

Comment: As a side note, you never need to write anything like `[x for x in sample_1_dict.items()]`. `list(it)` is exactly the same thing as `[x for x in it]` (and, if you're using Python 2.x, you've already got a `list` in the first place, so you don't even need that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very simple, and very general, solution to this.

Any time you have an iterator (a file, a CSV reader, a generator, whatever) that you want to iterate over multiple times, you can just toss it in a `list`:

```
with open('genes.csv') as f:
    cread = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t'))
```

Then the rest of your code can remain unchanged (or you can pull it outside of the `with` statement):

```
sample_1_dict = {i: float(j) for i, j in cread}
sample_1_list = [x for x in sample_1_dict.items()]
sample_1_genes_sorted = sorted(sample_1_list, key=lambda expvalues: expvalues[0])
sample_1_values_sorted = sorted(sample_1_list, key=lambda expvalues: expvalues[1])
sample_1_genes = [i for i, j in sample_1_values_sorted]
sample_1_values = [j for i, j in sample_1_values_sorted]
sample_1_graph_un = [float(j) for i, j in cread]
```

The downside of doing this is that you have to build an otherwise-unnecessary list, and you can't start your processing until you've read the whole file. If you can write your whole algorithm as a sequence of one-pass transformations from one iterator to another (e.g., generator expressions), that's a huge win.

But in your case, you're already building up a number of lists and dicts, and you can't get to the second one until you've read the whole file, so there's really no cost to building the list at the start.

Comment: This will be my preferred solution. The final graph is not properly overlaying the datasets with the new method, but may be an unrelated problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot read from a file, or a `csv.reader()` object twice without reopening or rewinding to the start.

Files are like a tape; as you read the file positions advances until it reaches the end. After that more attempts to read from them only results in no data being returned.

To rewind a file, use the `.seek()` method:

```
f.seek(0)
```

Note that your code seems to do an awful lot of extra work that is entirely not needed. `[i for i in ...]` merely loops over the input sequence building a copy of the sequence, where no actual copies are needed.

In fact, you don't need to read anything twice, the code can be simplified to:

```
sample_graph_list_un = []

with open('genes.csv') as f:
    cread = csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t')
    key_values = [(i, float(j)) for i, j in cread]
    sample_genes = sorted(k for k, v in key_values)
    sample_values = [v for k, v in key_values]  # unsorted for appending first
    sample_graph_list_un.append(sample_values)
    sample_values = sorted(sample_values)       # sorted() creates a copy
```

Note how the code addends to the `sample_graph_list_un` list; there is absolutely no need for you to build 6 separately named lists from separate `csv` files and then later combine them into one list here.

I didn't see how you used the sorted `_genes` and `_values` lists, I included them in the code but didn't append them anywhere. Use them in a similar vein, or completely remove the lines with `sorted()` if you do not need these lists anywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure it's actually documented/guaranteed that you can rewind a `csv.reader` like this. But if not… it seems pretty guaranteed that you can drop the reader, rewind the file, and create another one.

Comment: @abarnert: it has worked for me in the past; once you reach EOF any buffers held by the `csv.reader()` are going to be empty too, and rewinding then means a next attempt at iteration means the reader finds new data.

Comment: @abarnert: That said, not sure what'd happen if you seeked before reaching EOF.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters: That solved the error raised, but doesn't look like the values are plotting correctly as per reopening of the csv file. I'll mark as correct and investigate further.

Comment: Well, "worked for me in the past" isn't really a guarantee (especially if, say, it worked for you in 2.7 but I'm using 3.3, or it worked for you in PyPy but I'm using Jython, …).

Comment: @abarnert: nope, it's not a guarantee; merely an observation.

Comment: @abarnert: The module treats the input as an iterator expecting lines; seeking on file objects resets their iteration buffer so seeking is safe, at least in CPython.

Comment: I still think it's safer to just create a new `reader` each time you rewind. I can't see how it would be harmful to do so, and I think it's clearer, too.

Comment: @abarnert: sure, creating a new reader is fine too. I see now that [`csv.reader()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) documents that it treats the first argument as an iterator producing lines, so it should be safe across versions as well.